# Interpret stochastic differential equation as deterministic one

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

let us assume the following ODE

$$ \frac{dA}{dt} +gA = X  $$

where $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $g$ is a factor. $X$ changes its value in every timestep $dt$ which means that $X$ is a stochastic process.

if we would simply solve this ODE deterministically, then the integrating factor would be found quickly:

$$A = \frac{\int e^{gt}Xdt+C}{e^{gt}}$$

where one knows that

$$\int e^{gt}Xdt = \int e^{gt}dB_t $$ with standard Brownian Motion $B_t$

So:$$A = \frac{\int e^{gt}dB_t+C}{e^{gt}}$$

When i compute the mean and variance of $A$ i get

$$\mathbb{E}(A_t) = Ce^{-gt}$$
$$\mathbb{V}(A_t) = \frac{1}{gt}$$

but when i interprete this ODE as an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process i get the same mean, but different variance...

where is the problem?

Comment: Where did you find this exercise? Saying that $\int e^{gt}Xdt = \int e^{gt}dB_t$ is actually quite inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $C$ is not a constant, though it is independent of $t$; it is random variable. So you cannot find the variance by the first method.

Comment: Is it possible to adapt this first method to get the same result?

Comment: What is the distribution of C?

Comment: The first mehtod cannot be used to find the varaince of $A_t$. @Calculator123

Comment: okay, so its only possible via the ornstein uhlenbeck process